# How to get current position of UIElement within its parent?

Tags: .net, wpf, position, controls, uielement

Lets say I have this XAML code:

```
<StackPanel Name="pan">
    <Button Name="but1" Content="Helllo" />
    <Button Name="but2" Content="all" />
    <Button Name="but3" Content="World" />
</StackPanel>
```

I my code behind I want to find out what are the coordinates of `but2` within `pan`. How do I do it ?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
private Point GetPositionOfBut2() {
   var positionTransform = but2.TransformToAncestor(pan);
   var position = positionTransform.Transform(new Point(0, 0));

   return position;
}
```